# First order Modelica model with null time constant

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'd like to figure out whether it's possible (and semantically legal) in Modelica to simulate a model of a first-order transfer function, with a **time constant equal to zero** (`T` below). I'm using  OpenModelica 1.15.0~dev-48-g3656b95, but I'm asking the question in a general Modelica context.

My context is experimenting Model Order Reduction on Modelica models, which brings me to try to use the `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.FirstOrder` with a *sometimes null* time constant. However, to make the discussion simpler, here is the flat model I'm working on (a simplification and adaptation of the standard `FirstOrder` block):

```
model FirstOrderZero
  import Modelica.SIunits;

  Real u "input";
  Real y "output";

  parameter Real k(unit="1")=1 "Gain";
  constant SIunits.Time T=0 "Time Constant";

equation
  u = 1;
  der(y) = (k*u - y)/T;

end FirstOrderZero;
```

I understand that the way Modelica tools operate a symbolic equation analysis,  the time constant `T` should be `constant` rather than a `parameter`. Indeed, for `T=0`, the differential equation gets degenerated into an algebraic equation `y = k*u`. Unless the Modelica simulation tool can generate different code pathways for different values of `T` (which I think no Modelica tool does, except maybe Modia in the future?), the fact that `T` is null or not should be decided at the beginning of the equation analysis.

What I don't understand is why the above model fails to simulate ("division by zero at time 0 [...] where divisor expression is 0.0" with OM 1.15 dev) whereas *it works* when the last equation is rewritten as:

```
 T*der(y) = (k*u - y);
```

I would assume that the symbolic equation analysis should reformulate the equation automatically? (I can see with OM Transformational Debugger that the equation becomes `der(y) = (k - y)/0.0` which, of course, breaks at simulation).

Or perhaps, is it *syntactically illegal* to write Modelica equations with a division by a null constant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Variability of T

If the time constant `T` is constant, a parameter, or maybe a (discrete) variable depends on what you want to do.

- the value of constants gets fixed during translation
- parameters can be changed after translation (so before a simulation is started), but not during simulation
- discrete variables can change their value during simulation, but only at event instances
- continuous variables can change their value during simulation

See [4.4.4 Component Variability Prefixes discrete, parameter, constant](https://specification.modelica.org/v3.4/Ch4.html#component-variability-prefixes-discrete-parameter-constant) in the Modelica Specification 3.4 for details.

For first order elements you usually use a transfer function that will not change during simulation, but the user should be able to set the value of `T`. Therefore `parameter` would be the natural choice.

## Why your simulation fails

By using a constant for `T`, the Modelica tool can optimize your equations more than it can when you use a parameter. And depending on how you write your equations, you will end up with a different optimized equation.

For `constant T=0` your original model reduces to

```
model FirstOrderZero
  Real u, y;
  parameter Real k=1;
equation 
  u = 1;
  der(y) = (k*u - y)/0;
end FirstOrderZero;
```

To solve `y` its derivative `der(y)` is needed - but it can not be computed, as a division by zero always occurs.

In the second case with  `T*der(y) = (k*u - y);` your model reduces to

```
model FirstOrderZero
  Real u, y;
  parameter Real k=1;
equation 
  u = 1;
  0 * der(y) = (k*u - y);
end FirstOrderZero;
```

The equation `0 * der(y) = (k*u - y)` results in `0 = (k*u - y)` and therefore `y = k*u`. There is no division by zero and the model can be simulated.

You see, even though Modelica is an acausal language, it can matter how you write your equations.

## What you can do

A first order element with T=0 is not a first order element anymore, but only a proportional gain. To model that, use the block `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.TransferFunction`.

If `T` is not zero, parametrize it like this:

```
Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.TransferFunction transferFunction(b={k}, a={T,1})
```

and if its zero use

```
Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.TransferFunction transferFunction(b={k}, a={1})
```

Comment: To make my question more precise (and maybe it is a silly one): I'm looking for a reference (for example the Modelica spec) which states that equations with a division by 0 are incorrect. Otherwise, why the symbolic equation analyzer could not cancel it? Agreed, this would involve multiplying the equation by 0, which indeed doesn't an equivalent equation.

Comment: I just checked that `Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.TransferFunction transferFunction(b={k}, a={T,1})` with `T` being a constant equal to zero fails similarly (division by 0 at time 0). This is coherent.

Comment: Well, divisions by zero are illegal. If you have a division by zero in your translated model you have a problem. In the example above we saw that the same equation could result in a division by zero or not, depending on how you write it.

Comment: Regarding your second comment: Of course. That's why you have to use `a={1}` in that case.

Comment: Multiplying an equation divided by 0 is not allowed. You would end up with `0/0` which is not defined.

Comment: Thanks @marco for your feedback. So I may summarize the reasoning like this: 1) it *mathematically* illegal to "simplify" a zero at the denominator of an equation so no Modelica engine would do this. 2) OpenModelica doesn't detect that the equation is broken by containing `.../0` so it generates a corresponding C code 3) The compiled model crashes with a classical "division by zero" error.
So all seems perfectly logical now, except maybe at step 2), where OM could raise an error, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly, good summary. If the tool should throw an error at step 2 is questionable. The code can be generated, so the the translation process is fine. Note that Dymola also translates the model, but it gives the warning `Evaluation caused division by zero (T=0), in (k*u-y)/T`.